# MVC theory/Cocoa: where to create model?

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller

I have an AppDelegate, an NSWindowController and some Views. What is the best place to define `DataModel * data;`, initialize `[[data alloc] initWithSomething]` etc.?

I suppose it must be done in WindowController (.h and .m), since model must be handled by the main controller. Am I right? I've got a small doubt about keeping a pointer to Model in AppDelegate...

Sorry if my terminology is not MVC-correct, I'm just studying...

Comment: maybe you can define your datamodel as a singleton and initialize it when you first need the data. anyway i suppose in a real project you will have to access the data from all the views you will later defien.

Comment: So, if I have 2 controllers, both of them should contain `DataModel * data;` in their interface, and the singleton logic must be under DataModel class implementation?